# unresolved identifier "completion"

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've got some code I've used elsewhere in the project and modified it to fetch user data, however there's an error saying that completion is an unresolved identifier that I'm unable to find the solution to.

I've attempted adding a completion block to the call itself, and read through Firebase documentation to try finding a solution how ever nothing seems to work.

```
func observeCurrentUser() {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return
    }

    CURRENT_USERS_REF?.child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let user = User.transformUser(dict: dict)
                completion(user)
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a trailing closure ( completion ) as your current statement `completion(user)`  shows that you haven't added it

```
func observeCurrentUser(completion:@escaping((User?) -> ())) {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    CURRENT_USERS_REF?.child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
        snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
                let user = User.transformUser(dict: dict)
                completion(user)
            }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the completion as a parameter on your method
then specify the dataType of the completion content.

```
func observeCurrentUser(completion: @escaping (_ user: UserModel )->(Void)) {
    guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
        return
    }

    CURRENT_USERS_REF?.child(currentUser.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
            let user = User.transformUser(dict: dict)
            completion(user)
        }
    })
}
```